Has any astronomer ever observed that after a specific star going supernova it became a Black Hole?
Do we have any observational direct verification and historic record of a star after going supernova was turned into a Black hole?

Please clarify what you mean by the loaded phrase "observational direct verification". Some would argue that we have no "direct observational verification" of GR black holes at all.

@ProfRob The question is easy to understand: Have astronomers ever observed a black hole star before it became a black hole?

@ProfRob For example, you observe the location of a supernova with your optical telescope then you go after a year and observe the same relative location in the sky and find an unusual gravitational pull at that same spot of apparent empty space where the star was located previously therefore  inferring to a BH? This is a direct observation of such an event and historic record. On the other hand detecting extreme γ-radiation from the same location I consider not being direct observation proof.

@Markoul11 - why would there be an 'unusual' gravitation pull? The mass of the supernova, minus energy released, went into the black hole. So, the gravitational force from that spot will be a bit less (because of the energy released) than from the original star.

@JonCuster IDK about you, but I'd call a ~90% reduction in mass "a lot" and not "a bit".

@KyleKanos - well, yes, but observing that on a stellar scale is quite difficult in general. I suspect more that many folks would assume that the black hole has a larger gravitation effect than the precursor star which would be incorrect.

@MissUnderstands We have observed various objects of various sizes that have characteristics that match what theory tells us to expect for black holes of those sizes. I guess that counts as "observational verification", but it's not exactly direct, IMHO.

Sure, we've seen plenty of gravitational lensing. But that generally involves light trajectories with impact parameters that are large multiples of the Schwarzschild radius, or the combined effects of a large number of light paths (like the EHT images of M87 & Sag A*). We don't have nice clean close light trajectories like those I posted here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/810981/123208

I believe the best observational evidence for the creation of black holes at the end of a massive star's life are not found in those that explode as supernovae but in those thought to collapse directly to black holes. The problem with a supernova event is that it might leave a neutron star or it might leave nothing at all. If you simply see no evidence for a remnant after a supernova explosion then that could mean it has left a black hole or it could mean it has left nothing at all. It is possible for the exploding star to have been part of a binary, in which case one could deploy the techniques used to study massive compact binary systems (e.g. study the accretion disc or the reflex motion of the companion) to try and establish that a black hole exists, but that is very difficult when the supernovae are extragalactic and hence very distant.
Instead, we have the cases where a previously identified massive star "suddenly" disappears with no explosion. There is no alternative model (afaik) to explain the disappearance of a massive star other than it reaching the end of its life and collapsing directly into a black hole. Example candidates are reported by Reynolds et al. (2015), Adams et al. (2017) and Neustadt et al. (2021).

"If you simply see no evidence for a remnant after a supernova explosion then that could mean it has left a black hole or it could mean it has left nothing at all." We can measure the gravitational lensing of the remnant. If there was nothing at all left, there would be ne gravitational lensing at that location.  An accretion disk at the location is also a bit difficult to explain is there was nothing at all left at the location. However, that is not a direct measurement.

@KDP No black hole has ever been discovered or confirmed by gravitational lensing and certainly not a stellar-mass black hole in another galaxy. An accretion disk IS evidence for a remnant but would only be present in a binary system; as I said

The only alternative model that comes to mind would be whoever lives there finishing their Dyson Sphere...

@Perkins maybe, if they could construct the whole thing on timescales of years, and mask any infrared signature.

@ProfRob The Even t Horizon Telescope claims to have produce images of the black holes at the centr e of theM87 and at the centre of our own galaxy. These are not actually images of the black holes themselves but of the accretion disks around them.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Horizon_Telescope

@KDP Those are supermassive black holes. Neither was a new discovery.

@ProfRob I am curious about your statement that only binary black holes have an accretion disk. Surely any Kerr black hole that has a surrounding gas cloud will have an an accretion disk. due to in spiralling gas?  A black hole that has orbiting star will all accrete matter from the orbiting star if it close enough. When you say the body has to be a binary black hole to have an accretion disk, you mean that both bodies of the bianry pair have to be black holes?

@KDP why would there be a surrounding gas cloud? Black holes with an accretion disc that we know of are either supermassive or fed by a companion.

@ProfRob Depending on what type of construction they go with, assembling it in a short period might well be a requirement, but masking the infrared signature would be a challenge. They could maybe hide it from us specifically if they knew we were here and looking, but that would raise its own, disturbing, implications.

@ProfRob wouldn't a super nova leave a lot of "stuff" around the exploded star, which could (partially) later form into an accretion disk?

@PaŭloEbermann " wouldn't a supernova leave a lot of "stuff" around the exploded star" = = no. the star guts are ejected at near c. We call them cosmic rays.

@MissUnderstands The bulk of the "star guts" are ejcted at a small fraction of $c$ (less than about 10%). But they are ejected, so I agree with the general point.

SN 1979C is a potential example, though it definitely depends on what counts as direct verification. See here for a paper which considers its bright and steady X-ray luminosity (tracked over 12 years) to be possible evidence for a stellar-mass black hole accreting material. However, they also consider an alternative explanation where the emissions come from a pulsar wind nebula.
SN 2022jli is another potential candidate. Oscillations in the light curve of the event are taken to imply the existence of a binary system consisting of a compact remnant and a companion star. See the paper here. In my skimming of the work it seems they do not really speculate on the exact nature of the remnant (whether it be a black hole or neutron star) other than a brief comment on p. 23 that if the remnant is a black hole, the event's Eddington luminosity ratio would be lower (and thus in my understanding more physically reasonable in a certain sense) than were the object a neutron star.
